# An equation $p^a=q^b+r^c$ for powers of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, diophantine-equations

I´m preparing for math contests and found the following problem from [this pdf](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~lavric/Santos%20-%20Number%20Theory%20for%20Mathematical%20Contests.pdf).

Find all integers $a, b, c >1$ and all prime numbers $p, q, r$ which satisfy the equation

$p^a=q^b+r^c$

($a, b, c$ and $p, q, r$ does not have to be distinct).

I guess we can solve this problem by examine possible divisors, from which we conclude that $p$ is a divisor in both $q$ and $r$, or none of them. But since $p, q, r$ are all primes, the first case is only possible if $p=q=r=2$.

If $p=q=r=2$ we see that $a=k+1$ and $b=c=k$ for some integer $k$ satisfies the equation. Let now $p, q, r$ be distinct. Then, because of parity, one (and only one) of them must be 2.  But I´ve not come further than that. Any suggestions?

Comment: The proposal such that it is necessary for each degree be solved separately. To some degree there are solutions for other solutions do not. And for some there is just not one simple solution. This hypothesis bill. You want there to prove?

Comment: You can get $p^a\equiv q^b\bmod r$, $p^a\equiv r^c \bmod q$, and $-q^b\equiv r^c \bmod p$, and then apply Chinese Remainder. Not sure how far that takes you, but it's a start.

Comment: Once stuck, I'd start looking to see if there are *any* solutions.  One comes to mind immediately:  $25=9+16$.  Fiddling with the sequence of odd perfect powers $9,25,27,49,81,121,125,\ldots,$, I see two more solutions: $81=49+32$ and $125=121+4$.  It'd be nice if this suggested an obvious pattern, but if it does, I don't see it.

Comment: @AlexRavsky, the OP had already observed (in the final paragraph) that the three primes can't all be odd.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a very partial answer.  The problem strikes me as *much* more difficult than its origin (a "practice" problem in a section on congruences in a book on number theory for math contests) would suggest.

As the OP observes, one of the three primes must be $2$.  Setting aside the obvious family of solutions $2^{a+1}=2^a+2^a$ (with $a\ge2$), we're left looking for pairs of perfect powers of odd primes whose sum or difference is a power of $2$ (and not $2$ itself).  This suggests scanning OEIS sequence [A244623](https://oeis.org/A244623):

$$9, 25, 27, 49, 81, 121, 125, 169, 243, 289, 343, 361,\ldots$$

Looking just for *consecutive* powers that *differ* by a power of $2$, I found

$$\begin{align}
25&=9+16\\
81&=49+32\\
125&=121+4\\
5041&=4913+128\\
\end{align}$$

(The last example is $71^2=17^3+2^7$.)  If there is a pattern here, I fail to see it.  Maybe one of the gifted 13-16-year-olds for whom the book was written can weigh in....

**Added later**:  A paragraph near the end of section D9 in Richard Guy's *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory* suggest this is, indeed, a very hard problem.  The paragraph considers the equation $p^m-q^n=2^h$, where the primes $p$ and $q$ and the positive integer $h$ are fixed, and the question is how many solutions $(m,n)$ there are.  According to *UPiNT* (third edition), it is apparently a fairly recent (2002) result that each triple $(p,q,h)$ admits at most one solution $(m,n)$.

Comment: I was one of the gifted 13-16-year-olds and I don’t believe in the pattern (except the sequence $2^a+2^a=2^{a+1}$), because my intuition says that the powers of different primes are “spread independently”. So there  should be only finitely many other solutions which are small enough to be rather quickly found by hand. Keeping this in mind, I wrote a program which checked all (10000) powers from OEIS sequence table. I found no powers that sum to or differ by $2^a$ (with $a\ge 2$), except those which you already found and $7^3+13^2=2^9$.

Comment: So there may be a simple way to show that the equation have no large solutions. I tried to play with the residues of the prime powers by some moduli, but without advances.

Comment: @AlexRavsky, very cool.  I played around a bit looking at sums as well, but failed to spot $343+169=512$.